# logrotate writing to old app.log.1 instead of app.log

Tags: linux, logs, syslog, rsyslog, logrotate

We have a custom application which is using syslog for logging , Right now we are facing an issue with logrotate that logs are being writing to urls.log.1 instead of urls.log , logrotate not creating url.log after rotation.we are using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server. How can we force logrotate to create urls.log after rotation ?

logrotate config (/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog)

```
/usr/local/app/log/urls.log
{
        rotate 10
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        su app app
        postrotate
                reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        endscript
}
```

If I manually mv urls.log.1 to urls.log  and run force logrotate ,this will be the output

```
considering log /usr/local/app/log/urls.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /usr/local/app/log/urls.log, log->rotateCount is 10
dateext suffix '-20170228'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
switching uid to 1000 and gid to 1000
renaming /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.10.gz to /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.11.gz (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 10), 
renaming /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.9.gz to /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.10.gz (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 9), 
renaming /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.8.gz to /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.9.gz (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 8), 
renaming /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.7.gz to /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.8.gz (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 7), 
renaming /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.6.gz to /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.7.gz (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 6), 
renaming /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.5.gz to /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.6.gz (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 5), 
renaming /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.4.gz to /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.5.gz (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 4), 
renaming /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.3.gz to /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.4.gz (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 3), 
renaming /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.2.gz to /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.3.gz (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.1.gz to /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.2.gz (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.0.gz to /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.1.gz (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.0.gz does not exist
renaming /usr/local/app/log/urls.log to /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.1
running postrotate script
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
removing old log /usr/local/app/log/urls.log.11.gz
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
```

If I force run logrotate again this will be the output

```
    rotating pattern: /usr/local/app/log/urls.log 
 forced from command line (100 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
switching euid to 1000 and egid to 1000
considering log /usr/local/app/log/urls.log  
  log /usr/local/app/log/urls.log does not exist -- skipping  ## urls.log is not creating
not running postrotate script, since no logs were rotated
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
```

Comment: You may want to add the `copytruncate` option.

Comment: I am not really sure if the `postrotate` script runs with credentials "app:app". You may modify the script to run `reload rsyslog` without redirecting stdout and stderr, and then force `logrotate` again by renaming the log file (as you did already) or running `logrotate -vf`.

Comment: @ridgy that is log permission not credentials (owner:group)

Comment: The log file owner/group and permissions are defined by `create 640 app app`. For the `su`directive, error messages say `Set the "su" directive in the config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.`. IMHO this says the _rotation_ is done as the user/group defined in `su`directive. But you might try the second part of my  former comment to see the output/error messages of `reload syslog`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the `copytruncate` option:

> `copytruncate`
>
> Truncate  the  original log file in place after creating a copy,
>                 instead of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new
>                 one,  It  can be used when some program can not be told to close
>                 its logfile and thus might continue writing (appending)  to  the
>                 previous log file forever.  Note that there is a very small time
>                 slice between copying the file and truncating it, so  some  logging  data  might be lost.  [...]

With this option, you *may* not have to use the `postrotate` bit.

Comment: "Note that there is a very small time slice between copying the file and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost" , I am worried about this part since our application is writing hundreds of lines per second

Comment: Do we have an alternate solution because I'm using Filebeat to read log files and send logs to Kafka. Filebeat recommends not to use `copytruncate` option to avaoid dulication which I was encountering when using copytruncate. 
I don't want to add `copytruncate`.

Comment: @ReyanshKharga You should ask a fresh question on the site about this. In it, you may link to this question for reference. If you do this, you have a greater chance of people actually seeing your question (and they may even be aware of the software you are using, which I am not).